# Iterating over Django QuerySet without pre-populating cache

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I want to iterate over all the objects in a QuerySet.  However, the QuerySet matches hundreds of thousands if not millions of objects.  So when I try to start an iteration, my CPU usage goes to 100%, and all my memory fills up, and then things crash.  This happens before the first item is returned:

```
bts = Backtrace.objects.all()
for bt in bts:
  print bt
```

I can ask for an individual object and it returns immediately:

```
bts = Backtrace.objects.all()
print(bts[5])
```

But getting a count of all objects crashes just as above, so I can't iterate using this method since I don't know how many objects there will be.

What's a way to iterate without causing the whole result to get pre-cached?

Answer (score 3):

First of all make sure that you understand when a queryset is [evaluated](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated) (hits the database).

Of course, one approach would be to [filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#methods-that-return-new-querysets) the queryset.

If this is out of the question there are some workarounds you can use, according to your needs:

- [Queryset Iterator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#iterator)
- [Pagination](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/pagination/)
- A [django snippet](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1949/) that claims to do the job using a generator
- [Raw SQL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#performing-raw-sql-queries) using [cursors](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-cursors.html).
- Fetch a [list of necessary values](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values-list) or a [dictionary of necessary values](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values) and work with them.

Here is a nice [article](https://medium.com/@hansonkd/performance-problems-in-the-django-orm-1f62b3d04785) that tries to tackle with this issue in a more theoretical level.